# How to inject different instance(s) for different context in ASP.NET MVC using StructureMap?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, structuremap

We are using classes inheriting from Registry to configure our StructureMap container in our ASP.NET MVC 4 application startup.

Some excerpt from one of the registry-classes:

```
For<ISomeInterface>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<SomeImplementation>();
```

We would like use different instances of our interfaces depending on the context. *(For example switching from database "online" mode to "maintenance" mode where everything is saved on filesystem; therefore using other interfaces (i.e. repositories) all over the place in our application)*

For example by default it should use `SomeImplementation` but when passing some kind of querystring in the url (to name a simple "context" scenario) it should use `SomeOtherImplementation`.

How can this be achieved for multiple interfaces/types?

Should we use **named** instances for this? Like:

```
For<ISomeInterface>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<SomeOtherImplementation>().Named("other");
```

I read about StructureMap **Profiles** but i'm not sure if this is the right way to go.
Should we use profiles for this? Like i.e.:

```
Profile("other", profileExpression =>
  {
     For<ISomeInterface>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<SomeOtherImplementation>();
  });
```

How can we switch different configurations on the fly?

```
ObjectFactory.Container.SetDefaultsToProfile("other");
```

This way? *(At what stage in mvc "life-cycle" this can happen at the earliest?)*

Can this be a temporary switch for just the current request or current users session?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, runtime configuration like this is best achieved using an [abstract factory](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) that is responsible for creating your dependency during runtime.

This dependency can then be registered with StructureMap like so:

**Your registry:**

```
public class StorageRegistry : Registry
{
    public StorageRegistry()
    {
        ...
        this.For<IDataStoreInstance>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<DataStoreAbstractFactory>().ConfigureStorage());
        ...
    }
}
```

Now your `DataStoreAbstractFactory` is responsible for creating and configure the necessary storage instance based on your configuration. As `DataStoreAbstractFactory` is now registered with StructureMap you're able to inject the necessary dependencies into it for determining which storage method to use.

**Implementation example:**

```
public class DataStoreAbstractFactory
{
    public DataStoreAbstractFactory()
    {
        // Dependencies to figure out data storage method can be injected here.
    }

    public IDataStoreInstance ConfigureStorage()
    {
        // This method can be used to return type of storage based on your configuration (ie: online or maintenance)
    }
}

public interface IDataStoreInstance
{
    void Save();
}

public class DatabaseStorage : IDataStoreInstance
{
    public void Save()
    {
        // Implementation details of persisting data in a database
    }
}

public class FileStorage : IDataStoreInstance
{
    public void Save()
    {
        // Implementation details of persisting data in a file system
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

Your controller/services or whatever are now completely unaware of what storage method they're using when accessing and persisting data.

```
public class UpdateController : Controller
{
    public IDataStoreInstance StorageInstance { get; set; }

    public UpdateController(IDataStoreInstance storageInstance)
    {
        StorageInstance = storageInstance;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...

        this.StorageInstance.Save();

        ...
    }

    ...

}
```