# Switching Databases using DI/StructureMap

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap, easynetq

I have an application that listens for messages on a queue and processes said messages.

Up until now I have had a separate instance of the application installed for each of our customers, each with their own database connection strings in the config file.  This is becoming a pain when it comes to updating the application.

Now I'm attempting to refactor this so I'm able to install one instance which has all the necessary connection strings, and will will switch between databases depending on some run time parameter - message.Client for example.

This is all fine if I wire up everything by hand....

```
var data = new MyData(message.Client);
var processor = new MessageProcessor(new Foo(data), new Bar(data));
processor.Process(message);
```

...but am struggling to get my head round how I even start to achieve this using a DI container.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using StructureMap;

namespace M.Test
{
    public interface IData
    {
        IEnumerable<string> Names { get; }
    }

    public class MyData : IData
    {
        private readonly string _client;

        public MyData(string client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Names 
        {
            get { return _client == "Client A" ? new[] {"One", "Two", "Three"} : new[] {"Uno", "Dos", "Tres"}; }
        }
    }

    public interface IFoo
    {
        void FooDo();
    }

    public class Foo : IFoo
    {
        private readonly IData _dataContext;

        public Foo(IData dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;
        }

        public void FooDo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(_dataContext.Names.First());
        }
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
        void BarDo();
    }

    public class Bar : IBar
    {
        private readonly IData _data;

        public Bar(IData data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public void BarDo()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(_data.Names.Last());
        }
    }

    public interface IMessageProcessor
    {
        void Process(Message message);
    }

    public class MessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
    {
        private readonly IFoo _foo; 
        private readonly IBar _bar;

        public MessageProcessor(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
        {
            _foo = foo;
            _bar = bar;
        }

        public void Process(Message message)
        {
            _foo.FooDo();
            _bar.BarDo();
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string Client { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static Container _container;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _container = new Container();
            _container.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<IData>().Use<MyData>(); 
                x.For<IMessageProcessor>().Use<MessageProcessor>();
                x.For<IBar>().Use<Bar>();
                x.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
            });

            MessageReceived(new Message {Client = "Client A"});
            MessageReceived(new Message {Client = "Client B"});
            MessageReceived(new Message {Client = "Client A"});

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void MessageReceived(Message message)
        {
            // Fine if I do this...
            var data = new MyData(message.Client);
            var processor = new MessageProcessor(new Foo(data), new Bar(data));
            processor.Process(message);

            // But would like to do this...
            var diProcessor = _container.TryGetInstance<IMessageProcessor>();
            diProcessor.Process(message);
        }
    }
}
```

From what I've read I can see that constructor parameters can be used with StructureMap.  For example:

```
x.For<IData>().Use<MyData>().Ctor<string>("client").Is(someValueAtRunTime);
```

...but can't figure out when/how someValueAtRunTime should be set, and whatever I try I question how thread safe it is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern to achieve run-time configuration like this is to use an the [abstract factory pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/). (See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704556/how-to-inject-different-instances-for-different-context-in-asp-net-mvc-using-s))

An abstract factory is essentially a normal factory object that's responsible for returning the correct database implementation based on your run-time configuration - however, instead returning a concrete type, your factory method returns an abstraction in the form of an interface or abstract class).

You register this factory class with StructureMap so it can also have its dependencies managed via StructureMap like so:

```
public class StorageRegistry : Registry
{
    public StorageRegistry()
    {
        ...
        this.For<IDataStoreInstance>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<DataStoreAbstractFactory>().ConfigureStorage());
        ...
    }
}
```

The factory class would look something like this (this example is taken from the answer referenced aboven but you can clearly see how it would be put together in your circumstance.

```
public class DataStoreAbstractFactory
{
    public DataStoreAbstractFactory()
    {
        // Dependencies to figure out data storage method can be injected here.
    }

    public IDataStoreInstance ConfigureStorage()
    {
        // This method can be used to return type of storage based on your configuration (ie: online or maintenance)
    }
}

public interface IDataStoreInstance
{
    void Save();
}

public class DatabaseStorage : IDataStoreInstance
{
    public void Save()
    {
        // Implementation details of persisting data in a database
    }
}

public class FileStorage : IDataStoreInstance
{
    public void Save()
    {
        // Implementation details of persisting data in a file system
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.