# Structure Map: Get service based on meta or context information

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, structuremap

I have two types of searches in my application: International and national search. Both have nearly the same data structures but different data sources. I've created two different repositories with the same Interface. Now I would like to request the corresponding repository based on context or meta Information with structure map.

For example, if the user is on the national search page, the IoC Container should inject the national repository into the Controller. If the user triggers the international search, the same Controller should be used but uses instead the international repository.

Is this possible with structure map? if yes, how can I achive it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach to injecting a dependency based on a runtime value(s) is to use a factory pattern (such as an abstract factory pattern).

This way you essentially inject a class that's responsible for determining the runtime value (say, the existence of a session variable) and then create the appropriate instance of your dependency (your repository) based on that runtime value.

I'd recommend taking a look at [Mark Seemann's blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/15/ImplementinganAbstractFactory/) on the abstract factory pattern, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28720314/963542) for an example of how to set it up.

Without wanting to self-promote, I've also put together a [blog post](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2015/02/changing-structuremap-configuration-at-runtime/) that goes into more detail on the aforementioned answer that should be of some use.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I thought this behaviour should be part of a IoC framework so I don't need to implement it on my own.

Comment: This presents a few questions. 1. Your IoC container is often configured before certain runtime values exist (in application_start). 2. Your IoC container is responsible for *managing* dependencies, should it really be aware of the business rules surrounding certain dependencies? What if a class's dependency depends on values calculated in the database. Should your IoC container know how to connect to database? I wouldn't say so. This is exactly the problem the abstract factory is aimed to resolve.

Comment: @Harald-K. Hopefully this has helped you solve your problem.

Comment: It does, even it was not what I've expected or hoped ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could use Named Instances like this
http://docs.structuremap.net/InstanceExpression.htm => Overriding Constructor Dependencies